# How to send a buffer as an image?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, buffer

I have images stored in GridFS and I have the code written to take the image back out and turn it into a buffer but I can't seem to find adequate documentation that will tell me what to do with the buffer in order to render an image. I am using the MEAN stack.

This is my code:

```
exports.getFax = function (req, res) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    Grid = require('mongodb').Grid;
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function (err, db) {
        var gs = require('mongodb').GridStore(db, '544f9c11759c7418566019b3,', "w");
        gs.open(function (err, data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.length);
            gs.read([data.length], function (err, data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(err);
                if (!err)

                    res.send(data);
            })


        });
    });
};
```

Console.log(data) reads `<Buffer 00>` I am not quite sure how to proceed as I am still relatively new to GridFS and Working with Buffers instead of images in a filesystem. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `read`.  Use `stream` instead:  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/gridstore.html#stream

I don't know if this code works... just looking at the docs but try something like this:

```
gs.stream(true).pipe(res);
```